# Formik with MaterialUI's TextField value update issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formik

I've a React functional component where I use Formik for my form management and MaterialUI V5.10 for styling. In my Formik form, I use several TextField elements along with a Canvas element.

I am having below two issues ...

Despite initializing Formik form element values with initial values, none of the TextField displays those values. The only way I can see them is if I use the 'defaultValue' property of the Textfield.. see below code snippet

```
const initialValues = {
    toEmail01: "<user>@xyz.co",
  };

return (
    <div>
      <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        //enableReinitialize={false}
      >
        {({
          submitForm,
          handleBlur,
          handleChange,
          isSubmitting,
          isValid,
          dirty,
          touched,
          values,
          errors,
        }) => (
          <Form>
            <div>
                 <Grid item xs={2}>
                        <Item
                          sx={{
                            width: "50em",
                            height: "20em",
                            variant: "outlined",
                            border: "solid",
                            overflow: "scroll",
                          }}
                        >
                          <Typography variant="">To</Typography>
                          <Box
                            component="form"
                            sx={{
                              "& .MuiTextField-root": { m: 0, width: "75ch" },
                            }}
                            noValidate
                            autoComplete="off"
                          >
                            <div>
                              <TextField
                                id="toEmail01"
                                name="toEmail01"
                                //defaultValue={initialValues["toEmail01"]}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                onBlur={handleBlur}
                                helperText={
                                  touched.toEmail01 ? errors.toEmail01 : ""
                                }
                                error={
                                  touched.toEmail01 && Boolean(errors.toEmail01)
                                }
                                margin="dense"
                                variant="standard"
                                fullWidth
                              />
                            </div>
                           
                          </Box>
                        </Item>
                      </Grid>
            </div>
          </Form>
         )}
      </Formik>
```

I am also facing another issue, on my formik form, I have a Canvas element which needs dynamic updates to a text which user enters and I use the useState() hook to update this value (from level state management). What I am noticing is, on every update of the text element entire functional component gets re-rendered and the values of other non-related TextInputs gets refreshed. Not sure how to avoid this. I tried enableReinitialize={false} and enableReinitialize with Formik but it doesn't help.

Answer (score -1):

If you're experiencing issues with updating the value of a MaterialUI `TextField` when using Formik, you can try the following approach:

Use Formik's `useFormikContext` hook to access the values and `handleChange` props:

```
import { useFormikContext } from 'formik';
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';

function MyForm() {
  const { values, handleChange } = useFormikContext();

  return (
    <TextField
      name="myField"
      value={values.myField}
      onChange={handleChange}
      label="My Field"
    />
  );
}
```

Make sure that the name prop of the `TextField` matches the name of the field in your Formik values object.

By using `useFormikContext` and passing the `handleChange` function to the `onChange` prop of the `TextField`, you should be able to update the value of the `TextField` in sync with Formik's values.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).